# How to change parameters realtimely in portaudio

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

with port audio, i want to change parameter realtime.

Like (with C):
  sine wave 440hz -> i input '500' with getchar() -> sine wave 500hz

But i cant find method.

anyone know good resolution ?

My vision : this code(http://goo.gl/UJJlTw) + getchar() (to change frequency from CUI/Terminal )

Comment: Is your problem with generating a tone with variable frequency, or with getting the input from the user without stalling the audio generation?

Comment: thanks comment.
its 'generatind a tone with variable freaquency'.
(Like-> http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__sine_8c_source.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simplified cut N paste which upon each invocation
increases / decreases the frequency - sounds sorta like 
repeating zureee zuraaaa, zureee zuraaa ...

```
var phi = 0,
    dphi = 2.0 * Math.PI * given_node.sample_freq /
    given_node.sample_rate;

for (var curr_sample = 0; curr_sample < given_node.BUFF_SIZE; curr_sample++, phi += dphi) {

    synthesized_output_buffer[curr_sample] = Math.sin(phi);
}

given_node.sample_freq *= given_node.freq_factor;

if (given_node.sample_freq <
    given_node.MIN_FREQ) {

    given_node.freq_factor = given_node.increasing_freq_factor;

} else if (given_node.sample_freq > given_node.MAX_FREQ) {

    given_node.freq_factor = given_node.decreasing_freq_factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This other example from portaudio documentation](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__write__sine_8c_source.html) shows how to generate a sine wave using the [synchronous write I/O method](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/api_overview.html#read_write_io_method).

Below is a simplified snippet from this example, which skips portaudio initialization calls and generates a single channel, focusing on the main signal generation mechanisms:

```
/* initialization */
int phase = 0;
int phase_increment = (int) (frequency * TABLE_SIZE / ((double) SAMPLING_RATE) + 0.5);
...
/* signal generation loop */
for (;;)
{
  ...
  for( j=0; j < FRAMES_PER_BUFFER; j++ )
  {
    buffer[j][0] = sine[phase];
    phase += phase_increment;
    if( phase_increment >= TABLE_SIZE ) left_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
  }
  err = Pa_WriteStream( stream, buffer, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );
}
```

Generating a sine wave with a frequency that changes in real-time is conceptually not that different from generating a sine wave with a fixed frequency. The main difference being that you need to update the `phase_increment` to match the new desired frequency. So, once you have read the `new_frequency` from the user interface, you would recompute `phase_increment` and be ready to generate the next samples :

```
/* signal generation loop */
for (;;)
{
  ...
  for( j=0; j < FRAMES_PER_BUFFER; j++ )
  {
    buffer[j][0] = sine[phase];
    phase += phase_increment;
    if( phase_increment >= TABLE_SIZE ) left_phase -= TABLE_SIZE;
  }
  err = Pa_WriteStream( stream, buffer, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER );

  /* now update phase_increment as per new frequency */
  phase_increment = (int) (new_frequency * TABLE_SIZE / ((double) SAMPLING_RATE) + 0.5);
  /* then next loop iteration will be generating a sine wave at the new frequency */
}
```

Note that the sine wave generation uses table lookup, where `sine` is a table containing precomputed values of the `sin` function over a complete 2π cycle. This is generally done for efficiency.